# AC unit dripping onto crawl space vapor barrier

Tags: plumbing, hvac, leak, crawlspace

I just bought a house whose crawlspace looks like it was partially converted to being sealed off.  Basically, they put down a vapor barrier and closed off the vents, but didn't finish the job.  On top of that, there's a PVC pipe from the furnace dripping what I assume is condensation onto the plastic, and that's what I'm here to ask for advice on.

The wood down there seems like it's in good shape now, but I'm trying to avoid future damage.  I talked to a couple inspectors about the crawl space prior to buying the house, but I'm trying to figure out which of their suggestions I should go with.  The easy solution is to undo what's been done with it and tear up the plastic, or at least cut a hole underneath where it drips, and let it drip into the gravel.  The other recommendation was to run the pipe off somewhere else or to join it to the house's sewage drain.

You can see about all there is to see in these two photos.  The short pipe in the second picture is dripping down the insulated pipe coming off the air conditioning unit and onto the plastic.  It's a pretty steady trickle when the AC's running.

[image: Crawlspace Photo 1]

[image: Crawlspace Photo 2]

In addition to this, I do need to re-open the vents (I was told they were re-opened before we closed on the house but they look closed to me) and re-insulate the AC pipe, but that all sounds straightforward.

Any advice on what to do here would be appreciated.  I can try to provide more info or details if needed.  Thanks!

Comment: You are correct in that you don't want this dripping this way.  I suggest that you'll want to plumb this drain so that it empties into an actual drain.  If water is left to collect on its own somewhere, the amount of water that is generated will almost certainly cause some sort of problem.

Comment: What's happening to the joist between the two PVC pipes? Has it been cut, or snapped and moved out of position?

Answer (score 1):

The short pipe looks like it's a condensate drain - which *will* trickle when the AC is operating. It needs to run to a drain or to the outside. It looks like the insulation over the pipes has been damaged by the condensate running over it, and will need to be replaced. Even if the drain wasn't running onto them, the pipes are cold, so will sweat unless they're well insulated - the C shaped insulation needs taping closed, or you can buy insulation with a ziploc type feature that closes it up.

Answer (score -1):

WORTH THE READ: HVAC and other moisture drainage in Crawl Space

If drainage water from HVAC - or any source for that matter - needs to drain inside solid walls that it is especially difficult to put pipes through, AND if there is already the potential of a moisture level higher than desired (check with a pro on what moisture level is "too much" - for us it is higher than 47%) - consider

1. installing an interior full-perimeter French Drain,
2. assure the French Drain terminates into a collection tank (15-18" diameter, 18-24" depth, covered except for elimination drain pipe), and
3. install an electric sump pump in the collection tank that will pump the collected water (from all sources via the French Drain) through a flex or fixed pipe OUTSIDE the interior (crawl) space to a point at least 1-2 feet away from the structure. (installation of the sump pump will necessitate a grounded/GFI-protected outlet near the site of the pump. (use professionals for this and anything else you aren't good at if you make it a DYI project...it's worth the one-time expense for safety!!)

In my case, we had the French Drain and pump system installed when we discovered an excessive moisture level during a rainy season, so when we had the HVAC in the crawl space (and in the attic) installed, we authorized the HVAC installers to run the pipes to the stone-filled existing French Drain, assuring that the HVAC drains emptied into the middle of the 12" wide stone area WITH an elbow on the end of the HVAC drain pipes aimed downward into the stone, and covered with vapor barrier (plastic sheet).

We went one step further with installing a dehumidifier in the crawl space, centrally located, with a drain pipe directly to the collection tank - with a modest down-angle assured on the dehumidifier drain pipe (Uber Important!). I clean the permanent dehumidifier intake filter 2x per year and check for any leakage on all the pipes annually. Again, you can pay a HVAC pro to do this when you have annual or semi-annual service done to your HVAC.
Problem solved - permanently!